# Business Travel to US for 5 months

Tags: usa, business-travel

I do have a business travel to the US that will last for 5 months. This includes technical trainings, knowledge transfers, project planning and client meetings. Im kinda worried since this initial trip of mine is too long. I do have return ticket and a hotel booked for 5 months.

- What do you think will be the possible questions by immigration officers to me?
- And what supporting documents from my company should I have?
- Any tips will also be a great help.

Comment: Do you have a US visa? That's where most of the documents and questions will happen. You can only enter on the Visa Waiver Program (if you're eligible) for 90 days, so you'd need a visa for this trip. In addition, a five month trip sounds much more like "working in the US" than an ordinary business trip and a visa that allows employment may be required.

Comment: Do you have a history of travel to the US? What kind of visa do you have and what justification did you use?

Comment: Yes. I do have a multiple entry visa valid for 10 yrs. This upcoming project will be big and most technologies are proprietary that's why a long duration of training is required. All of the "work" in making the system will be done back in my country.

Comment: Hi Berwyn, this is my initial travel. I do have a B1/B2 Visa, Multiple entry valid for 10yrs

Comment: Where are you from? Can you answer about history of travel to the US? I doubt I can give you a good answer to your question but it might help others. I've probably spent at least 5 years in the US on various different visas and I still can't rate your chances.

Comment: Hi Berwyn. Im from Philippines and I haven't travelled to the US. Im just kinda anxious because of things I read from forums.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about.

I did the same thing a while ago - for 7 months - and the officers asked me the usual stuff, which company, what work, etc. You answer them truthfully about duration, content (training, project discussions and coordination meetings, customer meetings, etc.), and that's it.

The core point is you are *not doing anything illegal or shady*, so there is nothing to worry. You have the correct paperwork, and they are only verifying the details.

Comment: He never asked anything to see (outside of my passport and visa). I had my return flight ticket and hotel booking ready, but he didn't care for it. I think the main point is that you answer consistent and don't sound avoiding or fishy. Don't try to hide details (like you want to sneak in a week of vacation at the end - that's legal and makes you more human)

Comment: Great! Seeing some good light now. If its okay, may I know the nature of your business?

Comment: @Bri, IT Project Management. I'm generally not publishing any more about me, sorry.

Comment: It's fine. i'm on Software Development, this business really entails long trips if necessary. :)

Comment: What visa type do you have?

Comment: And remember that _illegal or shady_ means different things in different countries; for example, here in the USA, buying a beer for someone young who "forgot" their ID can get you in trouble.

Answer (score 8):

Just updating this now, I am now in US for about a month having my trainings. Here's what happened during the immigration officer in Point of Entry:

He asked me my purpose of visiting US, and how long I will stay. I said 5 months, he was quite skeptic because of the long duration of training, he asked for supporting documents like invitation letter and list of trainings I will be attending into and why will it take that long. I told him that the purpose of the training is actually a knowledge transfer because the project our company got will be developed back in my country and I am the one who leads it. He asked me the what is the nature of our services/projects. And he stamped my i-94 for 6 months.

Comment: Well done and thanks for coming back and updating us

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to suggest an answer and hope that someone else will come along with more knowledge.

I've entered the US dozens of times, probably hundreds, on multiple visa types and also on an ESTA many times. Hence, I'm probably considered a small risk and won't get the same type of interview as you. I have had many interrogations though! I also have many colleagues who have related their experiences to me.

If I were you, I would probably request an entry for a shorter period than 5 months. Perhaps 2 or 3 months. My reasoning would be that as a visitor with no prior history, a 5 month entry might be rejected as indicating that the purpose of entry is for work. If I received a 6 month entry stamp, I would then consider changing my flights to leave later.

At immigration, you must do as you have said and talk about training, meetings, knowledge transfer. Do not mention the word "work"!

Comment: Thanks a lot Berwyn! My company already bought the ticket good for 5 months though as well as hotel reservations.  I'm now asking them to provide me -  a guarantee letter that I will return, a contract/bond that I need to return to my home country and  an invitation letter attached with the full overview of my itinerary that includes the trainings, meetings and knowledge transfer. Do you think will that be good? Asking for prayers too. :D

Comment: The thing about guaranteeing you will return is good for a typical visit, but you need to persuade the immigration officer you are not there to work. That is a big deal. Is it possible that your company could split up your visit if it were necessary?

Comment: I think it's too late now since all things were set and the expenses were paid. This is giving me anxiety

Comment: @Bri Maybe another visa type would be indicated, such as [L-1](https://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/entrepreneur-visa-guide).

Comment: Ok, well you've got to go with what you have. I would go there with a detailed itinerary of your activities for the 5 months. They should be lists of meetings and training activites.

Comment: @phoog - L1 was not considered since the actual development of the project will happen in my home country. I just need go to the US to have the knowledge transfer, trainings and project plans. It is a big project that's why the trip is good for 5 months

Comment: @Berwyn Yes! Thanks. Just have to make things well planned as possible.

Comment: Ok, Bri. I suggest drawing up an itinerary for every week. List the meetings, attendees, who you will train or who will train you. Try not to leave any gaps where someone might draw a conclusion that you're working

Comment: @Berwyn! Thanks. This is a great help. I just need to accomplish all the supporting docs needed